In a freertos task, memcpy to a local variable causes device halt when the task suspended forcibly
For example, If Task1 suspended by calling osThreadSuspend forcibly while running,
my device halted sometimes. I guess there is a memory problem but don't understand why.
Could you explain why?
static void Task1(void const* argument)
{
    while(1)
    {
        if(condition)
        {
            char* src = NULL;
            char dst[length+1] = {0,};

            src = strstr((char*)uartRxBuffer, prefix);
            if(src != NULL)
            {
                memcpy(dst, src, length); // --> halt here
                ...
            }
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
}

I found that memcpy causes the device halt when the condition is true.
